# Create subset index based on value of another variable - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

On one side, I have a variable `num` which takes `int` values from 0, 1, 2, etc. up to 4 lets say.

On the other hand, I want to create a `dstack` using a variable `imgs` in which I have insert an index. `imgs` has a lengh of 40

```
num = [0,1,2,3,4] 

rgb = np.dstack((imgs[0], imgs[1], imgs[2]))
```

So, what I am looking for is a trick in which when `num=1`, then the `imgs[]` index should be 0, 1 and 2. Then when `num=1`, the indices should be 10, 11, 12. When `num=2`, then 20, 21, 22 etc.

Any idea how to create this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: *(for seeing this is correct I add `print`)*

```
num = [0,1,2,3,4] 

rgb = []
for n in num:
    rgb.append(np.dstack((imgs[{n *10}], imgs[{n*10+1}], imgs[{n*10+2}])))
    print(str(f'np.dstack((imgs[{n *10}], imgs[{n*10+1}], imgs[{n*10+2}]))'))
```

Output:

```
np.dstack((imgs[0], imgs[1], imgs[2]))
np.dstack((imgs[10], imgs[11], imgs[12]))
np.dstack((imgs[20], imgs[21], imgs[22]))
np.dstack((imgs[30], imgs[31], imgs[32]))
np.dstack((imgs[40], imgs[41], imgs[42]))
```

Comment: Thanks, makes the trick! accepting this one as i prefer not to define a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below (replace `do_something` with your actual function call)

```
def do_something(value):
    print(value)

nums = [0,1,2,3,4]
for x in nums:
    arg = 10 * x
    do_something((arg,arg + 1,arg + 2))
```

output

```
(0, 1, 2)
(10, 11, 12)
(20, 21, 22)
(30, 31, 32)
(40, 41, 42)
```